# Creating a prompt given an action in a *separate* software?

Tags: javascript, python, button, embedded, prompt

I'm looking for a way to create a prompt to fill in the serial # of a part when a program is run on this machine. The issue is, I don't have access to the software the machine uses. Is it at all possible to create an independent button/prompt/form etc. that can be triggered by an action in a software that I don't have editing access to?

Comment: Depends what the action is and what its side effects might be that you could detect and/or hook into.

Comment: The action would just be hitting a "run" button in the software which starts the machine on a program. Does this sound like something that could be hooked onto?

Comment: What does "start the machine on a program" mean?  If that corresponds to launching a new process that's pretty easy to detect.

Comment: it just means that the run button causes the machine (a wire bonder) to begin running some wire bonding program, are you thinking like a physical process that triggers the prompt?

Comment: I mean a process on the machine triggered by invoking an external executable (one you'd see in `ls` or in Task Manager etc).